# Determine if rails is running under a web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I tell if rails is running under a web server, as opposed to a script or irb?

For context: I'm tracking an ActiveRecord object, and I want to email alerts if the objects changes, **but only** if the changes came through the web interface.

Comment: Are you using production mode locally? Normally you would differentiate between production/development/test for these sorts of things.

Comment: Usually no, but sometimes we'll use the console or script to change stuff in the production database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found something that works, though it's not very pretty

```
$0  # => "irb" (for script/console) 
    # => "/some/handler.fcgi" (for webserver)
    # => "/some/script.rb" (for a script)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have the task of my application performing several startup checks prior to starting up specifically as a server. In my particular case I want to make sure that a special `User` record exists in the database since API calls made to my application require this `User`.

I use the following hack in one of the initializers responsible for startup checks:

```
if defined? Rails::Server
  puts "Running as a server..."
  # Perform checks here...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but isn't the fact that if your model access occurs through a controller interface (i.e. some action) then, by definition, an access through a web interface?

Rails doesn't run under irb. Yes, you can access objects and state under the `console` but that's not a web server access.

I think you just need to set up some filters in your controllers to implement your tracking logic for the models of interest and then you can differentiate between general access and web-server access (which is controller initiated).

Make sense?

Comment: Hey bjg, thanks for your response. When I say irb, I mean console. Filters are a great idea, but I'm not exactly clear how that would work.  The controller in question isn't very RESTful, and updates several different models. How would I detect this from a filter?